# Can I install a visual basic application on android?

Tags: android

I have been trying to code and run the hello world application but am not able to get the emulator to boot all the way. Plan b is vb.

HELP!

Comment: What is your emulator issue?  Break it down into one thing at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean VB or VB.NET?

[The Mono project recently announced VB.NET support](http://www.mono-project.com/VisualBasic.NET_support), though C# is the preferred language (do yourself a favor and switch!). Since [Mono runs on Android](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:ARM) (and just about everything else), it should get you going in the right direction.

**Update** Okay, downvoters: a little lesson in basic math: the [transitive property of inequalities](http://www.mathwords.com/t/transitive_property_inequalities.htm) states that if a < b, and b < c, then a < c.

So:

1. [If VB.NET can be compiled by Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/VisualBasic.NET_support),
2. [and Android supports the Mono framework](http://www.sdtimes.com/MONO_BRINGS_NET_TO_ANDROID/By_David_Worthington/About_ANDROID_and_MONO_and_NET/34199),
3. Then Vb.Net can be used to write an Android application.

We can get into a discussion about the available features, framework completeness, etc, but the OP asked about compiling "Hello world" in VB for Android.

Or, skip the above references and just consider this: The MS VB compiler produces MSIL/CIL.

[Just take the CIL that the compiler produces and throw it into Mono.](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/common-intermediate-language-and-its-role-in-net-mono.aspx) The Mono compiler will convert this to IR, optimize it and produce the appropriate binary for the target platform.

If you're going to downvote, cite your sources instead of arbitrarily throwing out acronym soup that is irrelevant to the topic at hand.

Comment: Android is not the same as "Mono runs on ARM". In order to use the Android GUI, you need to interface via JNI to the UI layer, which there are no existing adapters for Mono. Writing one would be possible of course :)

Comment: No, but VB runs on Mono, and Mono runs on Android, therefore VB runs on Android. Feature availability is an entirely different discussion.

Comment: Feature availability is implied. Obviously, the question is asked by someone with limited Android experience and the easiest interpretation of your answer is "Mono lets you code in VB for Android".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can not run a visual basic application on Android. Maybe if you provide some additional information about the problem you are having with the emulator we can help with that?

Comment: When I look at the logCat there are many, many, many errors and warnings. Eventually the emulator disconects and I am left we a none working emulator or the programs I am trying to code are not complete

Answer (score 1):

I'll guess at the emulator issue...

Sometimes the emulator can be quite slow. If you are impatient and start clicking on buttons in the emulator before it has finished, it doesn't seem to work properly. I did this when I first started and thought the emulator was broken - but it actually just took several minutes to launch. My clicking on buttons just made sure it never finished.

Try running your helloworld program, but be sure to wait until the emulator is fully ready to go before you interact with it.
The good news is, once you have launched the emulator once, you can keep the emulator running while you write and try out your code.

Comment: Does anyone have a working program I can use to test my installation of the eclipse environment and adt. I need to start troubleshooting at the logCat, I think!

What do you think?